# Symfony - httpclient post to external api

Tags: php, symfony

i'm trying to integrate a payment solution into my e-commerce website.
The official documentation of the payment solution provider (saferpay) ask me to POST some data to their API.

As i am a beginner with Symfony, i checked the official documentation to found how to post to external API and found out **HTTPCLIENT** service. (i'm using Symfony 4.4.20)

There's the way how i tried to implement it :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/checkout", name="app_checkout")
     */
    public function initializePayment()
    {
        $payload = array(
            "RequestHeader" => array(
                "SpecVersion" => "1.7",
                "CustomerId" => "307998",
                "RequestId" => "0a71fa0241d68c49387f8aee8f982a7b",
                "RetryIndicator" => 0
            ),
            "TerminalId" => "17735964",
            "Payment" => array(
                "Amount" => array(
                    "Value" => "100",
                    "CurrencyCode" => "EUR"
                ),
                "OrderId" => "123test",
                "Description" => "Test_Order_123test"
            ),
            "ReturnUrls" => array(
                "Success" => "localhost:8000",
                "Fail" =>  "localhost:8000"
            )
        );

        $request = $this->client->request(
            'POST',
            'https://test.saferpay.com/api/Payment/v1/PaymentPage/Initialize',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json'
                ],
                'auth_basic' => ['API_258086_74490074', 'THE PASSWORD'],
                'body' => json_encode($payload)
            ]
        );
    }
```

But i'm still facing the same error : "**HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized returned for "https://test.saferpay.com/api/Payment/v1/PaymentPage/Initialize".**"

I have contacted my payment solution provider and they told me that the data i'm trying to send seems to be OK.
It looks like the problem is with Symfony. (Or rather the way i implemented the HTTPClient request...)

Anyone knows where does this error come from please ?

Thank you for helping!

(Sorry for my english. I know it's not verry good...)

Comment: You don't want to post to an API in a controller because that is the web visitor. Instead make a curl request with php to send whatever is needed to the external endpoint. Depending on what is returned you then then use PHP to read the response and update the users view. This is not a Symfony thing but a php thing. Use PostMan as a helper. It has export code tools that you can easily place in your Symfony controller to process whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error you're facing is because of an authorization error. If you [look here](https://httpstatuses.com/401#:%7E:text=The%20request%20has%20not%20been,applicable%20to%20the%20target%20resource.), you'll see that:

> "The server generating a 401 response MUST send a WWW-Authenticate
> header field1 containing at least one challenge applicable to the
> target resource. [...] If the request included authentication
> credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has
> been refused for those credentials".

Are you sending credentials on header request? or are your credentials the right credentials? Without misspelling or something?

Answer (score 0):

**You get a 401, that means your API wants you to identify who you are, but you failed to do so.**

My best guess is that some headers, used for authentication are missing, or their value are invalid, e.g. `'auth_basic' => ['API_258086_74490074', 'THE PASSWORD'],`

The easier way to debug is to output the raw HTTP request, via `$httpLogs = $request->getInfo('debug');`. With the raw request, you'll be able to see what is missing, by asking the API support.